# Ignore Slash while using encryption in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, urlencode, urldecode

I have a problem to encrypt/decrypt the email, i just send a link on mail like this

```
http://www.domain.com/mycontroller/myfunction/McvBsce........etc
```

The last Segment is actually a encrypted email id, I decrypt this email and update stus in my db when user click on this link.All done right.

Problem: When url like this

```
http://www.domain.com/mycontroller/myfunction/McvB/sce
```

It shows 404 error, because slash included in the generated encryption key.How can i ignore the slash while it generate the encryption, that's my main problem, rest are working fine.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use this class, include this file in your `applicatio/libraries` folder, I had the same issue:

```
class MY_Encrypt extends CI_Encrypt
{
    /**
     * Encodes a string.
     * 
     * @param string $string The string to encrypt.
     * @param string $key[optional] The key to encrypt with.
     * @param bool $url_safe[optional] Specifies whether or not the
     *                returned string should be url-safe.
     * @return string
     */
    function encode($string, $key="", $url_safe=TRUE)
    {
        $ret = parent::encode($string, $key);

        if ($url_safe)
        {
            $ret = strtr(
                    $ret,
                    array(
                        '+' => '.',
                        '=' => '-',
                        '/' => '~'
                    )
                );
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    /**
     * Decodes the given string.
     * 
     * @access public
     * @param string $string The encrypted string to decrypt.
     * @param string $key[optional] The key to use for decryption.
     * @return string
     */
    function decode($string, $key="")
    {
        $string = strtr(
                $string,
                array(
                    '.' => '+',
                    '-' => '=',
                    '~' => '/'
                )
        );

        return parent::decode($string, $key);
    }
}
```

Credit goes to the codeigniter forum, from where I got this.

Comment: Show Fatal Error "CI_Encrypt Not Found"

Comment: THNX Nil'z, My issue solve and Guyz NOte ONE thing File name should be MY_Encrypt.php , but load in controller with the same peice of code $this->load->library('encrypt');

Comment: I used a custom naming for these functions so that I can still use the core functions. `custom_encode()` and `custom_decode()`

Comment: then you try to `$this->load->library('encrypt');`
    `$this->encrypt->encode($key);`

Comment: Thanks. This works.  For others, make sure you autoload this in your autoload.php file, like this: 
$autoload['libraries'] = array('encrypt','my_encrypt');